# How to automatically pass an argument to a function when it is called implicitly kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

maybe I phrased my question a little strange, but something became interesting to me.

Let's imagine that I have some `Extension` function:

```
fun Int.foo() {
    TODO()
}
```

Suppose that I need to pass the context of the `Fragment` from which I call it to this function, in which case I would do it like this:

```
fun Int.foo(context: Context) {
    TODO()
}
```

Here we are explicitly passing the `Context` of our `Fragment` to the function. However, I'm interested in the question - is it possible to somehow change this function so (or can it be called in some other way) so that I do not have to explicitly pass the `Context`?

I understand that I could do like this:

```
fun Fragment.foo() {
    var context = this.context
}
```

...however, I need an `Extension` function just above `Int`, so this method is not suitable.

Are there any ways how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're looking for [context-dependent declarations](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/context-receivers.md) that let you combine multiple receiver scopes:

```kotlin
context(Fragment)
fun Int.foo() {
    check(context != null) // context is actually Fragments context
}
```

Keep in mind however this feature is still in experimental state so it requires opt in by adding `-Xcontext-receivers` to your compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

The Int class is just a class for op with numbers
It doesn't make sense to contain a Context object
It is not possible to get context without passing it to the function
There are other ways, which is to create a static object for the application class
for example

```
class App : Application() {


companion object {
    var app: App? = null
}

init {
    app = this;
}
```

}

and then

```
fun Int.foo(){
    val context=App.app
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a interesting way